# C concatenate string variable string

Tags: c, concatenation, string-concatenation

I try to concatenate in the following form "string", variable, "string";

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
        char *name = "Lannister";

        char write_letter[50] = "Here you are Mrs. ", name, " Welcome!\r\n"
                             "Getting Started\r\n"
                             "Interviews\r\n"
                             "Take-home Projects\r\n";
}
```

does anyone have idea how to do it?

I saw an example of
**sprintf(write_letter, "Here you are Mrs. %s Welcome!", name);** 
but it is very difficult when i use large texts.

Comment: Sprintf  works.  Snprintf is better.

Comment: I found a "sugar" solution with macros **#define NAME "Lannister"** and **"Here you are Mrs. " NAME " Welcome!\r\n";**, but I do not know much about macros!

Comment: For a constant value, using a macro is fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the name is already decided at compile time and if there is no necessity to change the name during runtime then by all means choose the simplest alternative, i.e. -

```
#define NAME "Lannister"

char write_letter[] = "Here you are Mrs. " NAME " Welcome!\r\n"
                      "Getting Started\r\n"
                      "Interviews\r\n"
                      "Take-home Projects\r\n";
```

> Compile with highest warning level set. When you do that you will
>   get a warning similar to "*initializer-string for array of chars is
>   too long*" (this is the warning generated by GCC). 50 is too small for
>   this array hence I have allowed the compiler to decide the array size
>   (i.e. 'write_letter[]').

If you need to change the string at runtime then use either strcat() -

```
char write_letter[150] = "Here you are Mrs. ";
char *name = "Lannister";
char *write_letter_post = " Welcome!\r\n"
                          "Getting Started\r\n"
                          "Interviews\r\n"
                          "Take-home Projects\r\n";

strcat(write_letter, name);
strcat(write_letter, write_letter_post);
/*Use strncat() to prevent buffer overflow possibilities.*/
```

or, sprintf() -

```
char *_write_letter = "Here you are Mrs. %s Welcome!\r\n"
                      "Getting Started\r\n"
                      "Interviews\r\n"
                      "Take-home Projects\r\n";
char *name = "Lannister";
char write_letter[150];

sprintf(write_letter, _write_letter, name);
/*Use snprintf() to prevent buffer overflow possibilities.*/
```

Answer (score 4):

You can only use the `"..." "..."` notation for *compile-time evaluable constant expressions*. Your's is a runtime construct due to `name`.

You need to use `strcat`, `snprintf` etc. for that.

Answer (score 1):

The pre-processor is able to do string concatenation for you, given that all strings involved are written directly after each other and that they are pure *constant string literals*. That is, the things surrounded by `" "`, not the variables. For example `"hello" "world"` will get changed to `"helloworld"` by the pre-processor.

This does not work with variables. If you have character arrays, you need to concatenate them with run-time functions such as `strcat`.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to `sprintf` (using `snprintf(NULL, 0, ...)` to know how much memory to allocate for the result), you can use `strcat`. But again, you are responsible for allocating enough memory to contain the final string !